# Bootstrap jQuery Datepicker limit datepicker to three days on first calendar with two calendars

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I have two Bootstrap Datepicker calendar fields. On the first calendar, person can only choose three days into past starting from today and On the second calendar I would like to set the `startDate` and `endDate` to today. If the selection is more than three days, alert with an error. Let's say today is 3rd of November. when person chooses 1st,2nd or 3rd of November on the first calendar, the second calendar will be 3rd of November. If person tries to choose October 31st, it gives an alert.

What I have (UPDATE):

```
<input type="text" id="startDate">
<input type="text" id="endDate">


    $("#dt1").datepicker({
        dateFormat: "dd-M-yy",
        maxDate: 0,
        minDate: -2,
        onSelect: function (date) {
            var date2 = $('#dt1').datepicker('getDate');
            date2.setDate(date2.getDate() + 2);
            $('#dt2').datepicker('setDate', date2);
            $('#dt2').datepicker('option', 'maxDate', date2);

            var dt3 = $('#dt1').datepicker('getDate');
            console.log(dt1);
            var dt4 = $('#dt2').datepicker('getDate');

            if (dt3 == dt4) {
                maxDate: 0;
                minDate: 0;

                var date3 = $('#dt1').datepicker('getDate');
                var date4 = $('#dt2').datepicker('getDate');
                date4.setDate(date3.getDate());
            }
        }
    });
    $('#dt2').datepicker({
        dateFormat: "dd-M-yy",
        minDate: 0,
        maxDate: 0,
        onClose: function () {
            var dt1 = $('#dt1').datepicker('getDate');
            console.log(dt1);
            var dt2 = $('#dt2').datepicker('getDate');

            if (dt2 <= dt1) {
                var minDate = $('#dt2').datepicker('option', 'minDate');
                $('#dt2').datepicker('setDate', minDate);
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: *"I have two Bootstrap Datepicker calendar fields"* -- From the code you posted it seems you have jQuery Datepicker, not Bootstrap Datepicker (Eternicode)! Which one are you using? If the latter one, then what is the problem with `startDate` and `minDate`? Check here - http://codepen.io/Abhitalks/pen/ojMpNN/

Answer (score 0):

So I used Bootstrap Datepicker and came up with this solution. Work fine so far.

```
var nowDate = new Date();
var today = new Date(nowDate.getFullYear(), nowDate.getMonth(), nowDate.getDate(), 0, 0, 0, 0);

$('#datetimepicker6').datepicker({
    startDate: "-3d",
    endDate: today,
    format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
    autoclose: true,
    todayHighlight: true
}).on('changeDate', function (e) {
    // Revalidate the date field
    $('#movieForm').formValidation('revalidateField', 'datetimepicker6');
});


$('#datetimepicker7').datepicker({
    startDate: today,
    endDate: today,
    format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
    autoclose: true,
    todayHighlight: true
}).datepicker("setDate", today).on('changeDate', function (e) {
    // Revalidate the date field
    $('#movieForm').formValidation('revalidateField', 'datetimepicker7');
});
```